# build ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:8143:87 when updating Angular 8 to 9

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**I have upgraded an app from  angular 8  to 9 version . when i do a build Getting the following build error**

build commands : ng build --base-href /test/ --watch, ng build --base-href /test/ --prod

[image]

**Package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/html2canvas": "0.0.33",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular cli version : 9.1.0 , node js version : 12.16.1,

**I am unable to build the app , I also tried deleting the node_modules folder and doing a npm install but getting same error. Not sure what i am missing, can anyone please help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have you tried setting "skipLibCheck" to true in the compilerOptions in your tsconfig?
2. Try downgrading your typescript package to the version 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Typescript module @type/jquery throws an error because jquery does not play well with the current typescript version. We can either downgrade the version of typescript or if we planning to use the latest version of typescript installing the latest version of @type/jquery would fix the issue.

These two simple steps worked for me.

```
 rm -rf ./node_modules/@types/jquery
 npm install @type/jquery3.5.5 // ( at this time  typescript Version 4.1.3 you can opt for latest version @type/jquery3.5.5)
```